# SpyOn not working properly - Angular

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-cli, auth0

When I run my specs I am receiving a failure with my integration test that indicates my **spyOn** for **Auth0 service auth.authenticated()** is not setting the correct return value. Basically, this spec should be returning a *truthy* value (id_token) in order for the **Log Out** button to be displayed. Since it is still showing the **Log In** button, I assuming the null value is sticking instead of being set to the string in the **AuthResponse** variable.

**Am I missing something in my setup?** Any help would greatly be appreciated.

```
//navbar.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'afn-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}


//navbar.component.spec.ts
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar.component';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

describe('NavbarComponent', () => {
  let component: NavbarComponent;
  let navbar: NavbarComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavbarComponent>;
  let auth: AuthService;
  let authResponse: string;


  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ NavbarComponent ],
      providers: [ AuthService ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavbarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });


  beforeEach(() => {
    auth = new AuthService();
    spyOn(auth, 'authenticated').and.returnValue(authResponse);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('Unauthenticated user', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
      authResponse = null;
      navbar = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should should display "Log In" button', async(() => {
      const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
      expect(compiled.querySelector('button').textContent).toContain('Log In');
    }));

    it('should receive a falsy response from auth.authenticated', async(() => {
      navbar.ngOnInit();
      expect(auth.authenticated()).toBeFalsy();
    }));
  });

  describe('Authenticated user', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
      authResponse = '23kjsfdi723bsai7234dfsfghfg';
      navbar = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should display "Log Out" button', async(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
      expect(compiled.querySelector('button').textContent).toContain('Log Out');
    }));

    it('should receive a truthy response from auth.authenticated', async(() => {
      navbar.ngOnInit();
      expect(auth.authenticated()).toBeTruthy();
    }));
  });
});
```

**Template for the Navbar component**

```
//navbar.component.html
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Auth0 - Angular 2</a>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-margin" (click)="auth.login()" *ngIf="!auth.authenticated()">Log In</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-margin" (click)="auth.logout()" *ngIf="auth.authenticated()">Log Out</button>
    </div>
```

**Auth0 Service**

```
//auth.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import Auth0Lock from 'auth0-lock';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  // Configure Auth0
  lock = new Auth0Lock('hcDsjVxfeZuAVWg39KIWFXV63n8DjHli', 'afn.auth0.com', {});

  constructor() {
    // Add callback for lock `authenticated` event
    this.lock.on('authenticated', (authResult) => {
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
    });
  }

  public login() {
    // Call the show method to display the widget.
    this.lock.show();
  }

  public authenticated() {
    // Check if there's an unexpired JWT
    // This searches for an item in localStorage with key == 'id_token'
    return tokenNotExpired('id_token');
  }

  public logout() {
    // Remove token from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
  }
}
```

[image: Test Output]

[image]

Comment: That makes no sense. The service instance that is created by Angular and injected into your component is different from the one that you create in your beforeEach function. You need to get the AuthService from the TestBed (i.e. the actual one), and spy on that instance. Also, assigning a new value to authResponse *after* you've already configured the spy to return its previous value won't have any effect.

Comment: so other than not instantiating the correct AuthService, to get have a proper return from the spyOn, I would have to create individual spies for each response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting hints from @JBNizet, I was not instantiating the AuthService from TestBed and I decided to make a separate spyOn for each response. Though it doesn't look DRY, it works.

Here is the solution for navbar.component.spec.ts:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar.component';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

describe('NavbarComponent', () => {
  let component: NavbarComponent;
  let navbar: NavbarComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavbarComponent>;
  let auth: AuthService;
  let falsyResponse = null;
  let truthyResponse = '23kjsfdi723bsai7234dfsfghfg';

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ NavbarComponent ],
      providers: [ AuthService ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavbarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    auth = TestBed.get(AuthService);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('Unauthenticated user', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
      spyOn(auth, 'authenticated').and.returnValue(falsyResponse);
      navbar = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should receive a falsy response from auth.authenticated', async(() => {
      navbar.ngOnInit();
      expect(auth.authenticated()).toBeFalsy();
    }));

    it('should should display "Log In" button', async(() => {
      const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
      expect(compiled.querySelector('button').textContent).toContain('Log In');
    }));
  });

  describe('Authenticated user', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
      spyOn(auth, 'authenticated').and.returnValue(truthyResponse);
      navbar = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should receive a truthy response from auth.authenticated', async(() => {
      navbar.ngOnInit();
      expect(auth.authenticated()).toBeTruthy();
    }));

    it('should display "Log Out" button', async(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
      expect(compiled.querySelector('button').textContent).toContain('Log Out');
    }));
  });
});
```